# Routing dynamic path url using react js

Tags: reactjs

app.js - using app.js i'm getting left menu list. Using routing i'm 
selecting  one of the value from the left menu.

For the first time i'm getting the path Url like http://localhost:3000/Messages/3  using this.props.location.pathname . While i'm clicking second time in the menu the page was not refreshing and not getting the path ex: http://localhost:3000/Messages/4

Because im using dynamic json data for left menu and with single routing file(Message Component).

I need page refresh for every time by selecting one of the value in the menu.

```
class App extends Component {

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          data :[]
        }
      }


      componentDidMount(){
       var data =[{"id": 2 ,"name" :"shiva"},{"id": 3 ,"name" :"krishna"},{"id": 5 ,"name" :"ravi"}];
            this.setState({data: data});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
    <div className="container">
     <div className="col-lg-4">
            <div className="container-top">
               <div className="col-lg-4 leftmenu-contact-bg">
               <div className="ex1">
             {this.state.data.map((res,index) => <div className="left-list" key={index}>
            <div className="right-content" >
            <NavLink to={`/Messages/${res.id}`} activeClassName="nav-link-active" >
            <span className="icon-list"><i className="material-icons icon-color">person</i></span><span className="numbers" > {res.name}</span>

            </NavLink>


            </div>
            </div>

            )}


            </div>
               </div>

            </div>
           </div>
          <div className="col-lg-8">
          <Switch>
           <Route exact path ="/Messages/:id"  component={Messages} />
              </Switch>
          </div>
          </div>

    );
      }
    }

Messages.js

import React from "react";


class Messages extends  React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      data :[]
    }

  }

  componentDidMount(){


alert(this.props.location.pathname);


}


render(){



    return(

      <div>

 <div className="chat-decription">




</div>

</div>);
  }
}

Url path :

http://localhost:3000/Messages/2
http://localhost:3000/Messages/5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route exact path ="/Messages/:id"  component={Message} />
```

and for this route your class should be like

```
import React from 'react';

class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <span>Message id is {this.props.params.id}</span>
    )
  }
}

export default Message;
```

[react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)